Coroutine flows collection with no replay if already consumed
I have a StateFlow in my ViewModel like this:
    private val _walletState = MutableStateFlow<ResultModel<WalletResponse>>(ResultModel.loading())
    val walletState: StateFlow<ResultModel<WalletResponse>> = _walletState.asStateFlow()

A new value is emitted in this flow on API response.
I am observing this flow in my Fragment class in a lifecycle-aware manner using:
lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.CREATED){
            viewmodel.walletState.collect{
            if(it.status==LOADING)
                playSomeAnimation()
            else
                navigateToNextFragment()
        }
    }
}

The issue:
If my app is in the background and API call arrives, my collector is invoked, and I try to navigate to next fragment. But obviously, it crashes with IllegalStateException because I was trying to do fragment transaction after my onSavedInstanceState had been called.
I can solve this exception using repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) instead of repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED). But then the challenge is that every time my fragment is resumed, my collector is invoked. So, if I am starting an animation when the state is ResultModel.Loading, whenever I go to the background and come back to the app, it is resumed and my collector is invoked again making my animation run again.
Question:
How can I make my flow collection lifecycle aware with replay=1 but it should not be replayed on collection, once consumed by collector.
PS: I don't want any workaround solutions or hacks like keeping a boolean flag or resetting the state to a default value.

I don't understand how can navigateToNextFragment() happen when your app is in background. The whole point of repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) is to prevent things like this, the navigation attempt must be happening somewhere else. Could you provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example?

@JanItor Sorry it was Lifecycle.State.CREATED. I have updated the question.

Have you seen the approach used in a similar situation in the official docs? I mean you have to use some kind of a workaround here.

You need to define a hasStateConsumed flag in your ViewModel and notify your ViewModel that you have consumed the state every time you collect your state and check that flag before you use the state emissions like this:
lifecycleScope.launch {
    repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
        viewmodel.walletState.collect { state ->
            if (!viewModel.hasStateConsumed) {
                if (state.status == LOADING) {
                    playSomeAnimation()
                } else {
                    navigateToNextFragment()
                }
                viewmodel.stateConsumed(true)
            }
        }
    }
}

And in your ViewModel do it like so:
class MyViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    private val _walletState = MutableStateFlow<ResultModel<WalletResponse>>(ResultModel.loading())
    val walletState: StateFlow<ResultModel<WalletResponse>> = _walletState.asStateFlow()
    var hasStateConsumed = false
        private set

    fun stateConsumed(isConsumed: Boolean) {
        hasStateConsumed = isConsumed
    }
    ...
}

Every time you update your _walletState in your ViewModel call stateConsumed(false) before it like this:
stateConsumed(false)
_walletState.update { 
    ...
}


This is more kind of a workaround rather than a solution. Also, it won't go well if I have multiple flows in my VM. I will have to create equal boolean variables. A better version of this would be to reset the state to a default value, every time you consume it and don't do anything when the emitted value is default.
But I don't want to do such workaround.

If you reset the state in Loading what will happen to Loading? @ankuranurag2

Technically, you could navigate even after onSaveInstanceState by setting allowStateLoss to true in FragmentManager.commit. But it is a bug prone approach I wouldn't recommend.
That leaves us with using repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED). As I understand the main problem in this case is the repeating animation. We could avoid dealing with flows and states and simply add a boolean flag to the ViewModel to control the animation. Call playSomeAnimation() only if flag is false and then set it to true. If necessary, reset the flag in navigateToNextFragment(). This is a simple approach, but it may be sufficient.

I think Flow.take() is what you need:
//It's also recommended to use viewLifecycleOwner when using
//repeatOnLifecycle inside Fragment
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {  
     viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED){
         viewmodel.walletState.take(1).collect { state ->
             //rest of the codes
        }
}


From the link mentioned above: When count elements are consumed, the original flow is canceled. I don't want my flow to be canceled as there can be new values too.

I think I misunderstood your requirement.  I thought you'll only be consuming it once and then wait for the fragment's lifecycle to re-enter the specified state to collect and consume again.
